# Types created by Selenium do not match browser types

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am testing a javascript function that, inside its body, performs a check if a provided object is an `Array`. Let's simplify it to this:

```js
function isArray(obj) { return obj instanceof Array; }
```

Then, I call this function from a selenium web driver:

```py
assert driver.execute_script("return isArray([1, 2, 3]);") == True
```

but the result of calling `isArray` is *false* even though the type of the object is `Array`. After some investigation I found that selenium runs scripts having a Sandbox object as `globalThis`, thus the prototype of the array input is `Sandbox.Array` which appears to be not the same object as `window.Array`, so the instanceof check fails.

Is there any workaround for this? It's not just the Array but every global type is affected. I use selenium to test javascript code and it's important to me that functions under test recognise objects created by selenium.
Could it be possible to configure the driver to use the `window` as the global object? I couldn't find it in the selenium documentation but tbh. their documentation at selenium.dev seems to be very lacking.

**Edit - example code:**

here is a dummy javascript function in my application that I want to test using selenium:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      function isArray(obj) {
        console.log("instanceof Array:", obj instanceof Array);
        return obj instanceof Array;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In a python script, I open the website above and execute the `isArray` method providing it with an array.

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox

driver = Firefox()
driver.get("http://localhost:8000/index.html")

assert driver.execute_script("return isArray([1, 2, 3]);")
# AssertionError
```

The assertion fails because arrays created from within selenium do not have `window.Array` as a prototype.
Instantiating `window.Array` explicitly works.

```py
assert driver.execute_script("return isArray(window.Array(1, 2, 3));")
# success
```

Comment: I've never heard of sandbox array, but couldn't you just do: `[1,2,3] instanceof window.Array` ?

Comment: The code under test does `x instanceof Array` which resolves to `x instanceof window.Array`. When `x` comes from selenium, the test fails because arrays created by selenium are not `window.Array`s but temporary `sandbox.Array`s

Comment: As an experiment, you can try starting a new driver session and run `console.log(globalThis)`. You can see that when run from browser console, globalThis is window, but when run from selenium, globalThis is Sandbox object that contains copies of all global types.

Comment: You're doing something silly but we can't tell what because you didn't post enough code. Where is isArray defined?

Comment: I added a concrete example which demonstrates the problem.